# How do I redirect the user with PHP after using jQuery's preventDefault() on a form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery, AJAX and PHP to validate most of the forms on my website. The actual input validation is done via PHP (I thought this would be best to prevent users from bypassing validation using the browser source code inspector to edit scripts), but I use jQuery and AJAX to load errors into an error message div below the form's submit button.

All of this works fine, but when a form is successfully submitted I'd like to call `header('Location: foo.php')` to send my user back to a certain page. However, since I'm using `preventDefault()`, my new page is being loaded into the error message div, making the browser window look like it has two pages on top of each other (the current url doesn't change either).

Is there a fix to this? I thought I might be able to unbind the event in the PHP file by including a script after the PHP code is done, but I was not successful.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var url = window.location.href.toString().split("=");
    var id = url[1];

    var title = $("#title").val();
    var content = $("#content").val();
    var submit = $("#submit").val();

    //this is where the PHP is loading the new page, along with error messages
    $(".form-message").load("/php/_create.thread.php", {
      title: title,
      content: content,
      id: id,
      submit: submit
    });
  });
});
```

End of PHP file:

```
<?php
    //if successful, exit the script and go to a new page
    $submissionSuccessful = true;
    exit(header('Location: /index.php'));
?>

<reference path="/javascript/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></reference>
<script type="text/javascript">

var submissionSuccessful = "<?php echo $submissionSuccessful; ?>";

if (submissionSuccessful)
{
    $("#title, #content").css(
    {
        "border": "2px solid #24367e"
    }
        );

    $("#title, #content").val("");
}

</script>
```

Comment: I dont think this is going to work the way you want. As you're handling the form submission with jQuery, you're basically halting any browser-level redirection possible by it. Instead, you would need to redirect (if successful) with JS, maybe with something like: `location.href = '/index.php'`

(Sorry, I submitted my comment way too early)

Comment: What do you mean by that? I have been able to redirect the user using a Javascript workaround, and at the very worst, with JS disabled, the user can click a button to go back home upon successful submission of the form. I would just like to know how to clear this up using PHP, or if I'm going about this completely wrong. This is the only problem I've encountered using my approach. My workaround is: `exit('<script type="text/javascript">location.assign("/index.php")</script>');`

Comment: I'd recommend a slightly different approach:

Instead of `$(x).load(url, data)` use `$.post(url, data, callback)`, the url should return some json like `{error:"message"}` or `{success:true}` (it could also be HTTP error codes instead!) then, back in JS, you could do a conditional on the response:

`if (response.error) { showError } else { location.href = '/index.php' }`

Comment: As @mxcoder said, you can't redirect the user using PHP when making an Ajax call. If you do, the request will follow that redirect and return the response from it (which is the page you redirected to). You need to do it with a `location.href` in your callback. JS code loaded through ajax won't be triggered. If the ajax request returns errors, show them and if it returns a success, redirect the user using `location.href`.

Comment: I also don't really understand what the title has to do with your issue or question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach I talk about is similar to this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = window.location.href.toString().split("=");
        var id = url[1];
        var title = $("#title").val();
        var content = $("#content").val();
        var submit = $("#submit").val();
        // AJAX POST request to PHP
        $.post("/php/_create.thread.php", {
            title: title,
            content: content,
            id: id,
            submit: submit
        }).done(function (response) {
            // response is a JSON document
            if (response.error) {
                // Here you basically modify the UI to show errors
                $(".form-message").text(response.error)
            } else {
                // Here you basically modify the UI to show success
                $("#title, #content").css({ "border": "2px solid #24367e" });
                $("#title, #content").val("");
                location.href = '/index.php' // REDIRECT!
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And in the server end

```
<?php
if ($someSuccessCondition) {
    $response = ['success' => true];
} else {
    $response = ['error' => 'The Error Message'];
}
echo json_encode($response);
exit();
```

Comment: You can probably replace `window.location.href.toString().split("=");` (which returns an array with the location) with just `window.location.href` (which will return a string with the location)

Comment: _Side note:_ You also only need to have the `location.href` if the call returns successfully. Since we're redirecting the user away from this page anyway, there's no need to set any css or empty any inputs.

Comment: Yeah you're right. But for the split second they can see the submitted form I want them to visually know that they did a great job.

Comment: @Dalsia - Won't they know that when it redirects? That's where they should get some feedback. Most users will probably not see these changes. They _might_ see something flashing before they redirect, but won't know what it was.

Comment: Yes, but there is a certain pleasantry about seeing your inputs cleared before being sent to the next page (in my opinion).

Comment: @Dalsia - Fair enough. It's your app so your opinion matters the most :-)